# what is the best way to pass an object form one thread to the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a small program that watches a web socket for changes. 
after a change it grabs a json file and Deserialize the Object. 
the thread that does this stores the data in an instance of a class.

i want to pass that object with all the new data to a method in the main thread.
so i can check it for changes and write it out to a file.

what is the best way to pass the hole object to the main threads method?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window

{

    public class JsonData
    {
        public  string[] Highlights { get; set; }
        public string[] Images { get; set; }
        public string Cur_carno { get; set; }
        public string Cur_desc { get; set; }
        public string Cur_bid_disp { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void socketIoManager(string ip)
    {
     var socket = IO.Socket(ip);

            socket.On(Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            });
      socket.On("_DATA", (data) =>
            {
                var Info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData>(data.ToString());

             // need to pass Info object to UpdateFeed()
            }
    }

    private void connect_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        socketIoManager(json_ip.Text);


    }

    private void UpdateFeed(object info)
    {

        // do stuff with info


        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);

        //write string to file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"dataX.json", json);

     }
}
```

Comment: That depends entirely on what the main thread is doing. How do events normally get executed on the main thread? Also: *why* does the work need to be done on the main thread? You seem to be doing just fine executing the deserialization on the worker thread, so what is stopping you from doing the checking and disk serialization on the worker thread? For that matter, **why do you have two threads at all** in an I/O bound program? Just use `await` and keep everything on one thread.

Comment: There are lots of articles on how to use async await with sockets to keep everything on the main thread; here's one for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605876.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @EricLippert, one situation I can think of right away is that name resolution is still synchronous in `HttpWebRequest` in .NET framework, even if you use the asynchronous methods.  The documentation even says to avoid using them in a UI thread.